# Dividing both sides by 5, when solving $x = 5(\sin y) + 2$ for $y$?

Tags: fractions, number-systems

How do I know which operations to do when solving an equation?
For example,
$$x = 5(\sin y) + 2 \tag1$$
If I wanted to make $y$ a function of $x$,
$$\begin{align}
x &= 5(\sin y) + 2 \tag2 \\[4pt]
x - 2 &= 5(\sin y) \tag3 \\[4pt]
\frac{x - 2}{5} &= \sin y \tag4 \\[4pt]
y &= \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x - 2}{5}\right) \tag5
\end{align}$$
I believe this is the correct answer, but I was wondering why it isn't this way:

$$\begin{align}
x &= 5(\sin y) + 2 \tag6 \\
\frac{x}{5} &= (\sin y) + 2 \tag7 \\
\frac{x}{5} - 2 &= \sin y \tag8 \\
y &= \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{5} - 2\right) \tag9
\end{align}$$

> Why is equation $(9)$ wrong?

Comment: Simply because $(5\sin y + 2) / 5 \ne \sin y + 2$.

Comment: You forgot to divide the $2$ by $5$. Otherwise, it would be correct.

Comment: Correct is $\,\large \frac{5s+t}5 = s+\frac{t}5,\,$ not $\,\large s+t,\,$ by the linked [distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1334429/242) for fractions (or reals).

Answer (score 2):

[@player3236's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3981584/dividing-both-sides-by-5-when-solving-x-5-sin-y-2-for-y/3981733#comment8215175_3981584) has already correctly pointed out the issue in your calculation: you simply make a mistake from (6) to (7) because you forgot to divide $2$ by $5$ as well.

In general, when you divide a nonzero constant into both sides of a equation, you need to do it for **each** term. To see a simpler example, if you have
$$
x=5y+2
$$
then, after dividing by $5$ on both sides, you get
$$
\frac15x=y+\frac25
$$
instead of
$$
\frac15x=y+2
$$

To fix your problem, check the following correct lines:

$$\begin{align}
x &= 5(\sin y) + 2 \tag6 \\
\frac{x}{5} &= (\sin y) + \color{red}{\frac{2}{5}} \tag{7'} \\
\frac{x}{5} - \color{red}{\frac{2}{5}} &= \sin y \tag{8'} \\
y &= \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{5} - \color{red}{\frac{2}{5}}\right)
= \sin^{-1}\left(\color{red}{\frac{x-2}{5}}\right)
\tag{9'}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

A lot of algebra boils down to doing the same thing to both sides of an equation. For instance, if I started with the equation:
$$x=y+1$$
I could subtract $1$ from each side to get
$$x-1=y+1-1$$
which doesn't look that useful - except that using what I know about addition and subtraction, I can figure out that $y+1-1$ must equal $y$ to deduce a more useful expression:
$$x-1=y.$$
It's easy to learn this sort of manipulation by rote, but what we're doing is just cleverly using a fundamental property of equality: if two things are equal, I can do the same operation to both, and they will remain equal.

I could do other correct manipulations, if I wished - I could double each side to get
$$2\cdot x = 2\cdot (y+1)$$
which would simplify to
$$2\cdot x = 2\cdot y + 2.$$
Would this be useful? Probably not - but it's certainly legal. The trick with solving algebraic equations is that you choose your manipulations cleverly - you try to sort of "unwrap" the variable you wish to solve for, usually by undoing whatever operations were applied to it. I mention this because it's important to remember that we're not just shuffling terms about from side to side - to get from $x=y+1$ to $x-1=y$, I didn't magically move a $1$ from one side to the other - I *subtracted* from both sides in a way that conveniently made $y+1-1$ and then cancelled.

In the given example, removing the $\sin$ since it isn't at fault here, if I start with:
$$x=5y+2$$
It's absolutely true that there are multiple ways to start: One way is to start by subtracting $2$ from both sides giving
$$x-2=5y+2-2$$
$$x-2=5y$$
and then dividing both sides by $5$ to get
$$\frac{x-2}5=\frac{5y}5$$
$$\frac{x-2}5=y.$$
This is a nice sequence to go about it, because $5y+2$ means "take $y$, multiply it by $5$, then add $2$" and if I want to undo that sequence of operations, I just undo each operation in reverse order - that is, "subtract $2$, then divide by $5$".

But, you're right that you can start in other ways: if I divide both sides by $5$, I get
$$\frac{x}5=\frac{5y+2}5$$
which would then simplify as
$$\frac{x}5=y+\frac{2}5.$$
This step - from (6) to (7) in your reasoning - appears to be where the issue arises. From there, I could subtract $\frac{2}5$ from both sides as
$$\frac{x}5-\frac{2}5=y+\frac{2}5-\frac{2}5$$
$$\frac{x}5-\frac{2}5=y$$
which is equivalent.

As long as you take both sides and do the exact same thing to each of them, you'll arrive at a correct statement at the end*. Succinctly put, the property we're using is that if $L=R$ then $f(L)=f(R)$ for any function $f$ - where that function could be "add $2$" or "divide by $5$" or anything else we might dream of. Algebra is just knowing the correct thing to do so that at the end your result is useful.

(*Caveat: Sometimes students will assume this goes both ways, but if you do something like "square both sides" you can end up with extraneous solutions. It's still true that if $L=R$ then $L^2=R^2$, but it's *not* true that if $L^2=R^2$ then $L=R$. This doesn't come up with adding and subtracting stuff from both sides or multiplying by non-zero coefficients since you can undo those operations)