# Is there no such identity as $\csc^2+\sec^2=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\csc^2+\sec^2=1?$$

I thought I could just use reciprocal from the other formula $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$, can you explain what's wrong?

Comment: Identity valid in what range?

Comment: ${1\over a+b}\ne {1\over a}+{1\over b}$; if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: I guess I get it now, so they are separate terms. thank you

Comment: Don't use `csc` and `sec`. Nobody knows what they are (I have to recheck every time which is `1/sin` and which `1/cos` - big confusion), they are unnecessary, don't naturally appear in any sensible natural laws and, as you have noticed, don't have a nice enough identity connecting them. There's an objective reason that $(\cos x,\sin x)$ are a natural choice: they are components of a unit vector at a certain angle (or components of a complex number $e^{i x}$), and as such, all the nice properties of vectors and complex numbers hold. $\csc$ and $\sec$ are just names for some derived expressions.

Comment: thank you for your insights though I can't seem to understand the last part, no worries though.

Comment: some of you may find the "Law of Universal Linearity" interesting http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630339/pedagogy-how-to-cure-students-of-the-law-of-universal-linearity

Answer (score 3):

You can't just "use reciprocal", as you put it, because
$$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$
is not the same thing as
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}$$

Comment: OH.  i thought they were two separate terms, like how you can "move" cos^2 to the other side so it'd be sin^2=1-cos^2

Answer (score 0):

Your algebra isn't quite right (you need to divide through each individual term in turn).

$$\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$$
So if you divide through by $\sin^2x$, you get:

$$1 + \frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x} = \frac{1}{\sin^2x}$$

$$ 1 + \text{cot}^2x = \text{cosec}^2x $$

likewise, if you divide through by $\cos^2x$, you obtain:

$$  \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x} +1 = \frac{1}{\cos^2x}$$

$$ \tan^2x + 1 = \sec^2x $$

Answer (score -1):

We have $sin^{2}x + cos^{2}x = 1$ .Taking reciprocal we get $1 / sin^{2}x + cos^{2}x = 1$ ,then converting sin to cosec and cos to sec and then taking lcm of denominator we get $sec^{2}xcosec^{2}x/sec^{2}x + cosec^{2}x$ = 1

[image]

Comment: Use brackets for $1/(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x).$

Comment: +1 Taking this one step further we have the 'other' Pythagorean identity: $$\sec^2 x + \csc^2 x = \sec^2 x \csc^2 x$$