# Function defined as the supremum of a sequence of functions - epsilon-delta proofs

Tags: real-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

I'm really confused with working with sequences of functions and their sup.

Let A be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $f_n : A \to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.

Suppose that for all $x \in A$ the sequence $f_1(x), f_2(x)...$ is bounded.

Define the function $g : A \to\mathbb{R}$ by: $g(x)=\sup\{f_1(x), f_2(x)...\}$

Then if we have some $a \in A$ and $\epsilon\gt0$, how would one go about proving that there is a $\delta\gt0$ such that, for all $x\in A$ with $|x-a|\lt\delta$ one has that $g(a)-g(x)\lt \epsilon$ ?

Additionally, how can we show whether the function $g$ is continuous?

I'm trying to do a standard epsilon-delta proof for the first part, but can't seem to introduce an $|x-a|$ term into the working.

Comment: Note that the thing you're trying to prove is precisely that $g$ is continuous!

Comment: So can we use a standard epsilon-delta proof? It doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Have you heard that the (pointwise) limit of continuous functions is not necessarily continuous?

Comment: No, I don't think so :/

Comment: There are probably many examples of this fact on this website. Find them, and then ask yourself whether the thing you're trying to prove is definitely true.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:
$$g(x) - g(a) \leqslant \sup g(x) - \inf g(a).$$
Use the fact:  $\sup A-\inf B=\sup(A-B).$

Comment: So, $g(x)-g(a) \leq sup g(x) - inf g(a) = sup(g(x-a)) \lt sup(g(\delta))$?

Comment: no, its $\sup(g(x)-g(a))$ and now use the continuity of $f_{n}$

Comment: This hint is not helpful, in my opinion. To Analysis is fun: it might be wise to check out this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630339/pedagogy-how-to-cure-students-of-the-law-of-universal-linearity question, and then reevaluate the manipulations in your comment.