# Why isn't the $\sqrt{80}=8$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wanted to calculate the square root of 80, so I did

$\sqrt{80} = \sqrt {81-1} = 9-1=8$

I do not know what I did wrong, can someone correct me, as $\sqrt{80}$ is about $8.944$.

Comment: The square root function is not linear.

Comment: There are extremely popular threads [Pedagogy: How to cure students of the "law of universal linearity?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630339/pedagogy-how-to-cure-students-of-the-law-of-universal-linearity/) (on Math.SE) and [Whence the "everything is linear" phenomenon, and what can we do about it?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/926/whence-the-everything-is-linear-phenomenon-and-what-can-we-do-about-it) (on MathEducators.SE). Out of curiosity, do you have any unique insights into why this phenomenon occurs, having just manifested it?

Comment: $$\sqrt{80}=\sqrt{81-1} = 9\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{81}}\approx 9\left(1-\frac{1}{2\cdot 81}\right) = 9-\frac{1}{18}$$ is a correct way to approach it. It is not difficult to realize that $8^2=64\neq 80$, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just calculate $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ as being equal to $a-b$.

This is a common misconception, as if $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ was actually $a-b$, this would mean $(a-b)^2=a^2-b^2$, or $a^2-2ab+b^2=a^2-b^2$, which is entirely incorrect (except if $b=0$).

You can only calculate a square root like this if it is in the form of $\sqrt{(a-b)^2}$, which evaluates to $\left(\left(a-b\right)^2\right)^{1/2}$ or $|a-b|$.

Comment: $|a-b|$, please don't drop the absolute value.

Answer (score 3):

It is wrong because $\sqrt{a^2-b^2} \neq a - b$, but $\sqrt{a^2-2ab+b^2} = a-b$ if $a \ge b$.

Answer (score 2):

Without digging into algebra here, from a arithmetic standpoint had $\sqrt{80}$ been $8$, then how about $\sqrt{64}$? Clearly those answers can't be the same,  can they?