# Is $\int_{0}^{1} {\frac {q} {1+q} f(q) dq}$ = $\frac {\int_0^1 {q f(q) dq}} {1 + \int_0^1 {q f(q) dq}}$ for $f(q)$ a probability density function?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, definite-integrals, bayesian

In *Probabilistic Reasoning For Intelligent Systems* by *Judea Pearl*, in chapter 2, the **three prisoner paradox** was handled.

One scenario was raised where $P(I_{B}^{'}|G_A)=q$ is assumed; here $G_A$ is the event of prisoner $A$ (the one that asks the guard) being convicted and $I_B^{'}$ is the event of the guard reporting that prisoner $B$ will be released. Here we consider the guard's bias towards reporting $B$'s release to be an unknown ($q$).

$P(G_A|I_B^{'})$ = $\frac {q} {1+q}$.

We can even assume a probability density function $f(q)$ for the random variable $q$ that varies between $0$ to $1$, in which case -

$P(G_A|I_B^{'})$
= $\int_{0}^{1} {\frac {q} {1+q} f(q|I_B^{'}) dq}$
= $\frac {\int_0^1 {q f(q) dq}} {1 + \int_0^1 {q f(q) dq}}$

I do not understand the transformation from second to third line here.

**Note** - $f(q)$, being a probability density function for $q$ varying between $0$ - $1$, I assume $\int_{0}^{1} {f(q)} dq$ = $1$.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/630339). What about $f(q)=\mathbf{1}_{q\in[0,1]}$?

Comment: @metamorphy I should have verified it with an example first. Now that you mention this, I think I will verify the second and third expressions (that I referred to in my query) for equality, numerically, with a few candidates for $f(q)$ that satisfy $\int_0^1 {f(q) dq}$ = 1. $f(q)$ = 1 is one such candidate and true it does not satisfy the equality. Hence, we already know it cannot be generally correct.

Did I understand your point correctly?

Comment: Exactly. The (counter-)example $f(q)=\frac23(1+q)$ is even easier to check, since all the integrands are polynomials: $I=\int_0^1 qf(q)\,dq=\frac59$, so $\int_0^1\frac{qf(q)}{1+q}\,dq=\frac13\neq\frac{I}{1+I}=\frac5{14}$.